# Table with arabic text corrupted when trying to colour cells

Tags: tables, babel, arabic

I have got this code to create an Arabic table:

```
\documentclass[18pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[arabic, provide=*, bidi=basic, layout=counters.tabular]{babel}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Times}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |l|l| }
\hline
     \cellcolor{blue!25}  ١. سفر التكوين  &   ١. إنجيل متّى \\
      ٢. سفر الخروج &  ٢. إنجيل مرقس \\
      ٣. سفر اللاويين (الأحبار) &  ٣. إنجيل لوقا \\
        ٤. سفر العدد &  ٤. إنجيل يوحنا \\
        ٥. سفر التثنية (تثنية الاشتراع) &   \\
 &  ٥. أعمال الرسل \\
        ٦. سفر يشوع &   \\
       ٧. سفر القضاة &  ٦. الرسالة إلى أهل رومية \\
      ٨. سفر راعوث &  ٧. الرسالة الأولى إلى أهل كورنثوس \\
      ٩. سفر صموئيل الأول &  ٨. الرسالة الثانية إلى أهل كورنثوس \\
      ١٠. سفر صموئيل الثاني &  ٩. الرسالة إلى أهل غلاطية \\
      ١١. سفر الملوك الأول &  ١٠. الرسالة إلى الأفسسيين \\
      ١٢. سفر الملوك الثاني &  ١١. الرسالة إلى الفلبيين \\
      ١٣. سفر الأخبار الأول &  ١٢. الرسالة إلى الكولسيين \\
      ١٤. سفر الأخبار الثاني &  ١٣. الرسالة الأولى إلى التسالونيكيين \\
      ١٥. سفر عزرا &  ١٤. الرسالة الثانية إلى التسالونيكيين \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that when I include `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` to colour cell backgrounds, the table gets corrupted as such:

[image]

What am I doing wrong please?

**Update:**
I have noticed that if I don't use two decimal numbers, they appear as expected (for example replace all 11 with 1 at the beginning of each line). Very strange..

Comment: It works with `bidi=default`, so very likely there is a bug in the lua bidi algorithm or some kind of incompatibility with `xcolor`. I’ve opened an issue: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/252

Comment: As a workaround, put the numbers inside `\mbox`’es.

Comment: Please put this as answer so that I accept it.

Comment: Not yet. It’s just a workaround. Right now I’m investigating what’s wrong.

Comment: Thank you......

Comment: Hello @JavierBezos, is it fixed please? And when will the latest version of babel be released and how can I use it?

Comment: It's fixed in the GitHib repository. I just got back from vacation, and I’ll release a new version next week.